# Button to avoid Email Template for some order

Tags: workflow, email-template, admin

I have a time based workflow which will fire Email template 90 days before End_Date__c on Order.
I would like to create a custom button to disable request if we want to avoid this occurring for some orders?
How can I do this? Any code would be very much appreciate it!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create one new field and need to incorporate that field in workflow filter criteria : -

1. Create on new checkbox field in the object.
2. create custom button and by using the logic make the value of the newly created field as **false.**
3. Incorporate that field in the workflow field criteria as true.

Now if you don't want trigger the email for any record just click the button , it will make the value of checkbox as false and once the workflow will run, it will not satisfy the criteria and the email will not get triggerd.